# Channel images find entry with no set image

Tags: query, channel-images

I'm making a site for a client which has about two thousand news entries that were imported from a WordPress installation, each entry is using a channel images field. However some entries are missing an image that needs to be uploaded. Is it possible to somehow write a query that would list titles or entry ids of entries that are currently missing an image? It's a pain to go through them all by hand.

Normally it's not a problem to just list entry titles where a certain field is empty but channel images uses a separate table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make an EE template with simple channel:entries loop and a conditional to see if the field is empty. If empty, print entry name, ID, whatever:

> {exp:channel:entries} 
>   {if thumbnail == ""} 
>   {title} 
>   {/if}
>   {/exp:channel:entries}

In this example **thumbnail** is the name of the channel images field.

Comment: thanks, it never occurred to me to just check with a simple conditional. I found out that channel images has a {if image:no_images} conditional that I can use...found out all the missing images now :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are looking for entries where *no* images have been added to the Channel Images field...

All you would have to do is query exp_channel_data where field_id_X is empty (with field_id_X as the Channel Images field). Even though Channel Images data is in another table, there is a marker in exp_channel_data when the field is not empty.

This isn't tested with the very *latest* version of Channel Images, but for previous versions this works for me:

```
SELECT entry_id 
FROM exp_channel_data
WHERE field_id_65 = ''
AND channel_id = '9'
```

Just update your `field_id` as appropriate for your Channel Images field and update the `channel_id` to match the channel of interest.